# How to express "Please don't put the clean stuff where the dirty stuff is put"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request, phrase-request, idioms

I have a clothes rack that is used to hang dirty cleaning cloth (see the picture)

[image]

Today my child hung my Tshirt on / from the rack (not sure "**on or from**").

What should I say to him?

"**Please don't put the clean stuff where the dirty stuff is put**"?

Comment: Try to use a positive not a negative. Almost all these "talking to toddler" questions are "How do I say 'don't do this'"  How about saying "Let me show you where to hang daddy's shirt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: "on the rack".
Second question: Your example sentence works. You could also say:
"Please don't put my clean clothes next to the dirty rags." 
or
"Don't hang clothes on the cleaning cloth rack."
The possibilities are many.